# InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

I recently resumed work on a project that had lain dormant for a year. It was using Angular on AspNet Core 1.1 and using an early version of OpenIddict 1.0. It was developed using VS2017.

I updated VS2017 to the latest release (15.7.5) but the project would not compile and when I fixed the compilation errors it wouldn't run. So eventually I bit the bullet and decided to update the project to Asp Net Core 2.1 and to use the latest version of OpenIddict. I have the project so it compiles but when it starts it gives the error in the title, namely "InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer"

I can't see what is wrong. I understand that somewhere a second scheme named 'Bearer' is being added, but I can't figure out where. I am enclosing below my Startup.cs in its entirety.

```
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SIAngular.DBContexts;
using SIAngular.Models;
using SIAngular.Services;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace SIAngular
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // Configure the context to use Microsoft SQL Server.
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection"));

                // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
                // Note: use the generic overload if you need
                // to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

            // Register the Identity services.
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
                //.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Configure Identity to use the same JWT claims as OpenIddict instead
            // of the legacy WS-Federation claims it uses by default (ClaimTypes),
            // which saves you from doing the mapping in your authorization controller.
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
            });

            services.AddOpenIddict()

                // Register the OpenIddict core services.
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                           .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
                })

                // Register the OpenIddict server services.
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC services used by OpenIddict.
                    // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
                    // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
                    options.UseMvc();

                    // Enable the token endpoint.
                    options .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

                    options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
                    options.DisableScopeValidation();

                    // Note: the Mvc.Client sample only uses the code flow and the password flow, but you
                    // can enable the other flows if you need to support implicit or client credentials.
                    options.AllowPasswordFlow();

                    // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                    options.RegisterScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                                           OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                                           OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);

                    // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
                    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

                    // Note: to use JWT access tokens instead of the default
                    // encrypted format, the following lines are required:
                    //
                    options.UseJsonWebTokens();
                    options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();

                })

                // Register the OpenIddict validation services.
                .AddValidation();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:53244/";
                    options.Audience = "resource_server";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    //options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                        RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role
                    };
                });


            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please exp-lain what I am doing wrong. My intent was to follow the OpenIddict examples but clearly I went wrong somewhere.

The full stacktrace follows:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String name, Action`1 configureBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__0(AuthenticationOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options, IDictionary`2 schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at SIAngular.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SIAngular\Program.cs:line 20
```

Answer (score 10):

I finally found the answer which is probably obvious to OpenIddict experts, but not to casual users.

Since I am using JWT the`.AddValidation()` after the registration of the OpenIddict server options is not needed. This is obvious in hindsight but I hope this helps someone else with this problem. I am sure I am not thbe only person dumb enough to have been caught by this and when I look at OpenIddict samples now I understand, but I think the comment "For JWT tokens, use the Microsoft JWT bearer handler." could be amended to "For JWT tokens, use the Microsoft JWT bearer handler and remove the call to AddValidation below.

Comment: If you think it would be clearer, don't hesitate to submit a pull request to update the samples ;)

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I have tried the below code and worked for me.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 // Code omitted for brevity
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/identity/";
})
.AddJwtBearer("AzureAD", options =>
{
options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/eb971100-6f99-4bdc-8611- 
1bc8edd7f436/";
});
}
```

You can read this complete document on the below URL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0

- I have tried other solution as well.
  Please check if you have multiple startup.cs files and you are using any authentication schemes in that files.
- and also check to publish folder/deployment folder, need to delete App_Data Folder before deploying fresh/ latest changes.